# Change the Highlight and Striped colors in Table on Materialize using a Helper?

Tags: colors, materialize, highlight, helper

Is it possible to change the color of the table classes for Highlight, Striped in Materialize with a helper as you do with other background and text colors?

For instance, in an element class I can do

`class="black yellow-text"` and that's what I see, but if I change the table to have white text, the highlight color makes it unreadable.

I change colors dynamically, so doing this through the helpers in the element class would be nice if it's possible.

If not, then can I override the default in a style tag on the element?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

A snippet of your code when posting questions would be preferrable (best since you said "that's what I see")... Btw... To override the default color when hovering with the mouse you can type the following css:

```
table.highlight>tbody>tr:hover {
    background-color: rgba(194, 206, 23, 0.5);      /* whatever color you want */
}
table.highlight>tbody>tr {
    color: red;                                     /* whatever color you want */
}
```

If you put the CSS in a separate file make sure to use the `!important` keyword, otherwise it won't take effect because materialecss' css will take precedence over ours. Like this:

```css
table.highlight>tbody>tr:hover {
    background-color: rgba(194, 206, 23, 0.5) !important;
}
table.highlight>tbody>tr {
    color: red !important; <!-- you could ignore the !important here since materialize doesn't give a default color -->
}
```

```html
<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    <table class="highlight">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Item Name</th>
              <th>Item Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
    
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Alvin</td>
            <td>Eclair</td>
            <td>$0.87</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alan</td>
            <td>Jellybean</td>
            <td>$3.76</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jonathan</td>
            <td>Lollipop</td>
            <td>$7.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Maybe you already know all that, maybe not... But next time if you want to see what's the behaviour of an element when it is hovered you can use the developer console by clicking on inspect from the context menu to go straight to the element you need. You can then trigger the :hover selector by:

1. opening the css selectors,
2. clicking on :hover
3. here it is :)

[image: where you can find the property we need]